# Read and Write .docx with Apache POI

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

Is there any sample code to copy content of a .docx file to another .docx file and retain the style of text using Apache POI? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
XWPFDocument sourceDoc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("C:\\desktop\\sample.docx"));
XWPFDocument destDoc = sourceDoc;
```

Now using the above code watever is in sourceDoc is copied to destDoc with the same format.

In the above code,sourceDoc is used as a template of sorts.